# PARSE Cloud and Raspberry Pi Zero integration

Tags: parse-platform, raspberry-pi, raspbian

There is a new Raspberry Pi Model came in the market which is of only $5. I am planning to integrate this with PARSE cloud. In the website of PARSE it is written that it supports Raspberry Pi model. I just wanted to be sure that the new model can be integrated with this or not.
Just a simple Yes or no can also help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The raspberry pi Zero is compatible with Parse, as is Arduino.

It looks like the things that are not are the MCU/WiFi embedded devices such as the ElectricImp, Spark Core and ESP8266.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a doubt, you said that Raspberry Pi Zero supports cloud but not ESP8266. I don't think that ZERO has wifi or ethernet port. Then how it uploads data to cloud.

My plan was to integrate ZERO with PARSE with the help of ESP8266. Because I can't think of any other way to do it with such a less cost.

Thank You

Comment: You can add an ethernet port or an ethernet controller over the SPI bus

Comment: ElectricImp has a [Parse library](https://electricimp.com/docs/libraries/webservices/index.html#parse).

Comment: FWIW you cannot run Parse without a node.js server hooking into Parse server. They are sunsetting Parse in 2017.

Comment: The PiZero does not have a wifi or ethernet Port but it  does however have two usb ports that you can put a wifi dongle into.